# Test Cox Proportional Assumption (cox.zph) for multiple columns using apply?

Tags: formula, apply, survival-analysis, cox-regression, cox

I have a dataset with many columns. I want to do a Cox regression for each one of the columns, so I used "apply". miRNA names are the predictor variables, the columns I want to do Cox regression in separated models. This is the code:

```
mirna_names <-colnames(DB)[33:54]
cox_cont = sapply(mirna_names, function(x){
  formula = as.formula(paste('Surv(years, AD)~', x))
  coxFit = coxph(formula, data = DB)
  summary(coxFit)$coefficients[,c(2,3,5)] %>% round(3)
})
```

Now, I would like to test Cox Proportional Assumption using "cox.zph". I want to do it for all the miRNAs again, so I used "apply". However, this doesn't work. Any help?

```
cox_assump = sapply(mirna_names, function(x){
  formula = as.formula(paste('coxph(Surv(years, AD)~', x))
  coxFit_assump = cox.zph(formula, data = DB)
  print(coxFit_assump)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A MWE would have helped, but the code below works.  I've made as few changes to your original code as possible.

```
library(survival)
data(capacitor)

mirna_names <- c("voltage", "temperature")
cox_cont = lapply(mirna_names, function(x){
  formula = as.formula(paste('Surv(time, status)~', x))
  coxFit = coxph(formula, data = capacitor)
}) 

cox_assump = sapply(cox_cont, function(x){
  coxFit_assump = cox.zph(x)
  print(coxFit_assump)
})
```

The issue had to do with the input for `cox.zph`.  It wants a `coxph` object, which you recognized, evident in how you were reestimating the models again.  However, your reestimated `coxph` had no `data` argument.  (The `data` argument present in your `cox.zph` line won't get passed to `coxph`.)  I sidestepped the issue entirely by looping over the `coxph` objects from the first `lapply`.